# Trying to Post Photo to API from Angular 13 / Capacitor but showing as BINARY

Tags: angular, capacitor

I have a call to our backend that works successfully from Postman

[image]

I am also trying to send the same POST from our Angular 13 app but the Body is showing as:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using to build the request body:

```
async takePicture() {
    const capturedPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
      saveToGallery: false,
      allowEditing: false,
      correctOrientation: true,
      source: CameraSource.Camera,
      quality: 100
    });

    const base64 = capturedPhoto.base64String;
    const imageName = 'test.jpeg';
    const imageBlob = this.dataURItoBlob(base64);
    const imageFile = new File([imageBlob], imageName, { type: 'image/jpeg' });
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('OnBaseDocType', 'OAP');
    formData.append('PalletPos', '01L');
    formData.append('Picture', imageFile);

    this.ionLoaderService.showLoaderAsync().then(() => {
      this.photoService.postPhoto(formData).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
        .subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            this.toastr.success('', 'Photo Saved', {
              timeOut: 3000,
            });
            this.ionLoaderService.hideLoaderAsync();
          }, error: (err) => {
            this.toastr.error('', 'Failed To Post Photo', {
              timeOut: 3000,
            });
            this.ionLoaderService.hideLoaderAsync();
          },
        })
    });
  }

 postPhoto(request) {   
    return this.http.post(environment.baseURL + 'v1/picture/adhocfp', request)   
  }
```

I thought the code above would convert the base64 to file and post the file itself. Our firewall is blocking the call from angular because of the size but successfully accepts the call from postman.

Is there a way to create the POST exactly the way it is in postman?

Comment: Is it resolved? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

`CameraResultType.Base64` returns just the base64 representation of the image, not the data url, if you want to get the data url you have to use `CameraResultType.DataUrl`.
The plugin will then return `dataUrl` instead of `base64String`.